# AutoScrolling with zooming image in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, zooming, autoscroll

I am new to iphone i am working on project in which  i am autoscrolling the image with scrollview also along with it i have to do zoom in and out of image.Is this possible ? and if Yes how it can be done.Please suggest me some code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

// 1
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"];
   self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
  [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

// 2
   self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size; 
  }
```

**viewDidLoad**

> 1. First, you need to create an image view with the photo1.png image you added to your project and you set the image view frame (it’s size
>      and position) so it’s the size of the image and sits at point 0,0
>      within the parent. Finally, the image view gets added as a subview of
>      your scroll view.
> 2. You have to tell your scroll view the size of the content contained within it, so that it knows how far it can scroll
>      horizontally and vertically. In this case, it’s the size of the image.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// 1
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

// 2
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
```

}

**viewWillAppear**

> 1. Next, you need to work out the minimum zoom scale for the scroll view. A zoom scale of one means that the content is displayed at
>      normal size. A zoom scale below one shows the content zoomed out,
>      while a zoom scale of greater than one shows the content zoomed in.
> 2. You set the maximum zoom scale as 1, because zooming in more than the image’s resolution can support will cause it to look blurry. You
>      set the initial zoom scale to be the minimum, so that the image starts
>      fully zoomed out.